# jQuery 2.0.3 bug - fadeIn(), show() broken in firefox - SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a very basic html element that I would like to `fadeIn()`. I am however using `require.js` so I believe this could be part of the problem. I am using jQuery 2.0.3  When using `fadeIn` I get this error:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
chrome://firebug/content/console/commandLineExposed.js
Line 5
```

I have never seen this before, I have reset firefox and my PC.

**Html**

```
 <message-box>
      <message-info></message-info>
      <close-box>x</close-box>
 </message-box>
```

**JS**

```
$('message-Box').fadeIn();
```

I only get this error with `firefox v27`. No other browsers are having this problem, but I haven't tested it in any older versions of `FF`

I am  not seeking help for anything other than the error...

[See the error in action?](http://m.sexdiaries.co.uk/) and run this command: `SD.message.showMessage('Somehow this breaks everything', 'bad');`

-----**Edit**-------

So sadly you'll need to test this [Here](http://m.sexdiaries.co.uk/) I assure you this is SFW, its just the sign in page.

I am confident there must be something in my other `JS` files that is conflicting, but I, as yet, have not found the problem.

I removed a fiddle that was here as it in no way helped the question, since adding the bounty I want it to be as helpful as possible.

**Second Edit**

Oddly, when running any `show(), hide(), fadeIn()` etc an iframe is created at the base of the page, just before the body. I'll need to have a think in my code why this would be happening.

**Third Edit**

I have no reason or explanation for this, but updating to jQuery 2.1.0 has fixed my issues. If anybody can explain the problem then I'd love to give them the points :)

Comment: This is not valid html.

Comment: Of course it is, its html5 my friend. When did you last read the spec :p http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/ and shame on the person who upvoted it.

Comment: Adding height:100% to messageBox seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/9Frn8/5/

Comment: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.MessageBox.html thought this might help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stepping through the jQuery code, you eventually hit this internal function below. The security error is thrown when jQuery attempts to write to the iframe document. jQuery 2.1.0 has a different way of determining the default node display value so you can just treat this as a jQuery/browser combo bug. You can minimally recreate the security error by pasting the following into the console:

```
var iframe = jQuery("<iframe frameborder='0' width='0' height='0'/>").css( "cssText", "display:block !important" ).appendTo(document.documentElement);
iframe[0].contentWindow.document.write("<!doctype html><html><body>");
```

Internal jQuery function:

```
function css_defaultDisplay( nodeName ) {
    var doc = document,
        display = elemdisplay[ nodeName ];

    if ( !display ) {
        display = actualDisplay( nodeName, doc );

        // If the simple way fails, read from inside an iframe
        if ( display === "none" || !display ) {
            // Use the already-created iframe if possible
            iframe = ( iframe ||
                jQuery("<iframe frameborder='0' width='0' height='0'/>")
                .css( "cssText", "display:block !important" )
            ).appendTo( doc.documentElement );

            // Always write a new HTML skeleton so Webkit and Firefox don't choke on reuse
            doc = ( iframe[0].contentWindow || iframe[0].contentDocument ).document;
            doc.write("<!doctype html><html><body>");
            doc.close();

            display = actualDisplay( nodeName, doc );
            iframe.detach();
        }

        // Store the correct default display
        elemdisplay[ nodeName ] = display;
    }

    return display;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) custom elements shall have '-' in their tags, so your markup should look like this:

```
<message-box>
  <x-message><div></div></x-message>
  <x-close>x</x-close>
</message-box>
```

After the change and corresponding style updates it works as far as I can tell: http://jsfiddle.net/9Frn8/11/

Comment: I will try this out on the working verion, not the fiddle version. The error only occurs on the link I gave.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this may be due to the absolute paths in your CSS file. I also see (in console) you are trying to do a call to localhost (which fails, of course). There seems to be some issues in your code that is causing Firefox to stop specific processes. Specifically, something that firefox considers cross-domain.

This is most likely a [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue.

Comment: humm interesting, I will have a look into this. Although calling this should not be doing any ajax calls. $('messageBox').show() you wouldn't expect an ajax call :)

Comment: Not at all. But your CSS file also has font family names like: C:\folder1\folder2\.....

Comment: Very good point about the local host, this is from `livereload.js`. I'll remove that and see where that leads :)

Comment: Try to take a look at the urls in your CSS file as well.

Comment: Updated, all calls are from same domain now... Still seeing the error sadly.